# update derby database exception

Tags: java, database, sql-update, derby

I wrote this code to update a patient in a derby database but it throws a `SQLSyntaxErrorException`. Am I missing something?

```
public void updateInDatabase(int ID,String sex, String firstName, String familyName, String eMail) {
    try {
        String sql = "UPDATE  PATIENT  SET sex = "+ sex +" WHERE NR = "+ID;
        st.executeUpdate(sql);
        String sq2 = "UPDATE PATIENTEN SET FIRSTNAME=" + firstName + "WHERE NR=" + ID;
        st.executeUpdate(sq2);
         String sq3 = "UPDATE PATIENTEN SET FAMILYNAME=" + familyName + "WHERE NR=" + ID;
        st.executeUpdate(sq3);
        String sq4 = "UPDATE PATIENTEN SET EMAIL=" + eMail + "WHERE NR=" + ID;
        st.executeUpdate(sq4);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DbManagerPatienten.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, you're missing the use of `PreparedStatement` to prevent syntax errors and [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks where hackers will steal your data and delete your tables.

Comment: As for the question itself, you're missing the part where you show us the full error message and what line causes it. It's usually best to post the full stacktrace.

Comment: Question: Is it deliberate that you're updating two different tables (`PATIENT` and `PATIENTEN`)? And why are you executing 3 different `UPDATE` statements to update 3 different columns of the same table. Will be *so much* better to do that in one statement.

Comment: my netbeans is on german so i have to translate to english and im not so good in english but i'll try to explain.

Comment: the error is in the first sql statement  st.executeUpdate(sq1)

Comment: the error roughly translated says "column male is not found in the FROM table-list

Comment: but male is the sex and is no column name but whats wrote in as data

Comment: the column name is sex so i don't know whats the mistake

Comment: Unrelated, but: you don't have to run three updates to update three different columns. You can update three columns with a single `update` statement. And please read the JDBC tutorial on how to properly use a `PreparedStatement`

Answer (score 2):

Your main mistake is that you use string concatenation, which will leave you vulnerable to [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Your specific mistake is that you didn't quote the text value.

```java
String sql = "UPDATE  PATIENT  SET sex = "+ sex +" WHERE NR = "+ID;
```

That Java statement results in `sql` having the following SQL statement:

```sql
UPDATE  PATIENT  SET sex = male WHERE NR = 42
```

The statement should have been:

```sql
UPDATE  PATIENT  SET sex = 'male' WHERE NR = 42
```

However, the correct way to do this in Java is to use a [`PreparedStatement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html), and to use try-with-resources.

See the following for more information:

- [The Java™ Tutorials - Using Prepared Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)
- [The Java™ Tutorials - The try-with-resources Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)

```java
String sql = "UPDATE PATIENT" +
               " SET SEX = ?" +
                  ", FIRSTNAME = ?" +
                  ", FAMILYNAME = ?" +
                  ", EMAIL = ?" +
             " WHERE NR = ?";
try (PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {
    stmt.setString(1, sex);
    stmt.setString(2, firstName);
    stmt.setString(3, familyName);
    stmt.setString(4, eMail);
    stmt.setInt   (5, ID);
    int updateCount = stmt.executeUpdate();
    if (updateCount == 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Patient not found: " + ID);
}
```